# Cannot install cvxopt on OSX 10.10.5

Tags: python, macos, cvxopt

I was trying to install cvxopt to my OSX system. But It didn't work.
I just followed the instruction of the standard installation on: http://cvxopt.org/install/#standard-installation. 
The response from the terminal is as follows:

running install
Checking .pth file support in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-527.pth'
```

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
```

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

Anyone could help me?
Thank you very much~

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install the package to a system owned folder location. You can overcome this by running `sudo python setup.py install`m but you will end up with a mess of installed libraries. Rather create a virtual environment in a location that your user owns. This way you keep your main python install clean and can chop and change versions as you need.

For more information [see](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)